# Can't change JIRA issue Status via REST call

Tags: rest, jira

I am attempting to resolve an issue in JIRA using the REST API.  When I make the call the comment is added, the resolution is set to 'Done' however the issue status doesn't change (it stays as Open not Resolved).  The JSON I'm using is:

```
{  
   "update":{  
      "comment":[  
         {  
            "add":{  
               "body":"Comment added when resolving issue via REST call"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "transition":{  
      "id":"51"
   },
   "fields":{  
      "resolution":{  
         "name":"Done"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried the above with transition ID=5.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details about what you tried. Which URL did you send your request to? What was the status code of the response? What was the body of the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this, I had to add "transitions?expand=transitions.fields" to the end of the URL to get it to transition.  So full URL was:

```
https://{jirahost}/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issuekey}/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```